# devise_token_auth - skip_confirmation_notification! not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

The confirmation mail is sent automatically when a user is created. But I need to send the mail through code manually after completing a few more steps.

I can't able to prevent the confirmation mail from sending.

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

   include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User

   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :confirmable

   before_create :skip_confirmation_notification!
```

I am using devise_token_auth with Grape API for rails.

**Note:** If I try to use **skip_confirmation!** it works perfectly without any flaw. But I don't need that functionality because I want to confirm the users only through the confirmation link sent to their mail.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to skip to send confirmation mail by doing this in your controller. put this code before the user save

```
resource.skip_confirmation_notification!
resource.save
```

so now confirmation mail will not sent than you can put conditions which you wants than when your condition is true. you can again send confirmation mail in by below code..

```
resource.send_confirmation_instructions
```

i personally tested it.. and it works great.. hope it will help you

Comment: skip_confirmation! automatically confirms the user. But I want to confirm the user only through the mail link.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable time buddy and sorry that I missed some important points in the question. Am using devise_token_auth with grape. So it would be better if I could handle it in model side as there are not controllers in my app. I am stuck with that. As I said, if I use skip_confirmation!, it works perfectly man